# Struts logic:iterate

Tags: java, struts

I'm using struts `logic:iterate` and I need to change the style on the last row that it writes out.

I have a `bean:size`, and `indexId` on the iterate tag, but I can't figure out a logic combination to say if `bean:size = indexId` because size is the size of the collection, and the max `indexId` is always going to size -1 because of starting at 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My last time I did Struts was early this year, so let me explain with best knowledge,

There is no way of determining the length of the collections by using `logic:iterate` (See explanation [here](http://struts.apache.org/1.0.2/struts-logic.html#iterate)). What you will have to do is the following:

Assuming your collections is placed under `request.setAttribute("collections", allMyCollections);`

You can use `EL` (Expression Language) to determine the size and determine if they are equal by using `c:if`, i.e. in this effect:

```
<logic:iterate name="collections" id="curElement">
    <c:if test="${curElement.indexId == ${fn:length(collections) - 1}}">
        <!-- It is pretty messy ...but you get the idea -->
        <!-- We are the last element...whoohoo!!! -->
    </c:if>
</logic:iterate>
```

Otherwise, use `<bean:size />` to get the size of the collections, set it to a variable and you'll use scriplets to get the stored collections size and use `<logic:equal>` tags to see if the last index is at `collections.size() -1` (but that's cumbersome).

Hope this helps.

**PS** The code is rough....

Answer (score 0):

This might come in late, but I think this is a little cleaner...

```
<logic:lessThan name="currentIndex" value="${myCollectionSize - 1}">
    Some style...
</logic:lessThan>
<logic:equal name="currentIndex" value="${myCollectionSize - 1}">
    Some style on the last element...
</logic:equal>
```

or in CSS:

```
someElement:last-of-type {}
```

OR

```
.someClass:last-child {}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: unfortunately, `:last-of-type` only works for actual types, not class selectors.